# Xcode build fails under Subversion control (using Versions)

Tags: xcode, svn, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, versions

I have this Xcode project that I use for building an App Store app (the code is generated by Titanium Appcelerator). So far it's been working fine.

But when I add my project to subversion (using Versions) and check it out, my build starts failing.

The error message thrown by Xcode is:

```
[ERROR] While reading /Users/ [some long local path] /._startup.png pngcrush caught libpng error
```

This looks like an image compression error, but I don't have an image named "._startup.png", I do however have one named "startup.png". So that made me look in the .svn/entries file located next to my image, and that has the string "._startup.png" in it.

My question is; How do I solve this?

I want my project under version control using Versions, but it's apparently conflicting with Xcode's build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "solved" the problem by deleting the png from the project, replacing it by a jpg. Then I committed that, cleaned out the project and made a test build, which worked. Then I added the png to the project again and committed that, cleaned the project and rebuilt. That seems to have worked, I don't really know what the problem with the mentioned SVN file might have been.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the original code in svn/Versions. Not the compiled code.

Since you have written the app in Titanium you better also store Titanium code. The generated code is not very usefull and not very maintainable.

Edit:

Apparently you already did that, and this is your answer: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Subversion

Comment: Actually I didn't store the compiled code in SVN, but it looks like the Titanium build scripts copies my SVN references from my Resources directory (and I need my Resources under version control).

Comment: why not use the build in git in Titanium Studio?

Comment: I don't really feel it's an answer to use another SVN client. I have not verified that this actually solves the problem but I don't see why it should, the problem seems unrelated to Subversion, and more to Titaniums build process.